# What is the difference between the DAC8562 and DAC8562T chips from Texas Instruments?

Tags: integrated-circuit, dac, texas-instruments, comparison

These two callouts have distinct product pages (https://www.ti.com/product/DAC8562?dcmp=dsproject&hqs=pf and https://www.ti.com/product/DAC8562T?dcmp=dsproject&hqs=pf) and distinct data sheets. I've spot-checked several pages of the PDF data sheets for these two chips with my eyeballs and, aside from typesetting differences and the different callouts for the chip part numbers, found the specs and text to be identical. I don't know of a diff tool that will work on PDFs! Rather than trying to discern a significant difference by manually comparing every page using my unreliable wetware, I'm hoping someone (from TI, perhaps?) might know what's up with this. These chips are obviously related, but the datasheets and product pages on the TI website for each part make no mention of the other. Is one just a die-shrink of the other?  Are they intended to be identical? Or is there an actual difference between the two parts documented somewhere in the 63-page data sheets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to TIs [E2E forum](https://e2e.ti.com/support/data-converters-group/data-converters/f/data-converters-forum/941678/dac8562t-difference-between-8562-and-8562t), the only difference is the digital input threshold levels.

The T version is designed to be compatible with 5V TTL logic levels  whils the non-T version uses CMOS voltage levels.

---

If you scroll down towards the bottom of the TI product pages, they show some of the E2E posts relating to each product which can be a rather useful source of info about their products.

Comment: OMG, that's it! Just like the difference between a 74HC00 and a 74HCT00! Now I can make an informed decision about which part to use for my design. Never would have found that without your help - thanks, Tom!